# Assign a remote server's IP to another server location

Tags: router, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, esxi, mikrotik-routeros

How we can assign a remote IP address to another server?

I have a VPS in Germany (Mikrotik RouterOS installed) and it has a valid IP address,

And in other side in Italy, I have another server which has installed Vmware ESXi (Installed CentOS VM & a Mikrotik Router OS inside it)

I want to assign and use the Germany IP address in Italy Server (CentOS) How can I do this ? I can use Mikrotik or any other solution using ESXi or Centos

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a way to reroute that ip directly unless the Germany VPS has the address routed to it (which if you have one address it isn't).

What you can do, on the other hand, is set up a VPN from the client to the server, and use dstnat to port forward what you need over to it.